# How to create new window in tkinter while letting pagest retain functionality

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am writing a database program for my A level, I have a series of tkinter pages that are designed to be linked by one central page. The search, delete and update functions successfully run SQL queries on their own but lose their functionality when called from the main page, I am getting no visible error messages. I am running SQLite 3.11.2 and Python 3.7.3

Below is the code needed for the main page.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import AttendancePage
import NEA_SQL_IIII

class Student:

   def __init__ (self,root):
       self.root =root
       self.root.title("ODIN")
       self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
       self.root.config(bg="ghost white")

       def ap():
           AttendancePage.Attendance(Tk())

       MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bg="Ghost White")
       MainFrame.grid()

       TitFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, padx=54, pady=8, bg="Ghost White", relief = RIDGE)
       TitFrame.pack(side=TOP)

       self.lblTit = Label(TitFrame ,font=('ariel', 47,'bold'),text="Welcome to the ODIN main page",bg="Ghost White")
       self.lblTit.grid()

       CallButtonFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, width=1350, height=70, padx=18, pady=10, bg="blue2", relief = RIDGE)
       CallButtonFrame.pack(side=TOP)

       self.btnAttend = Button(CallButtonFrame, text = 'Attendance page',height=5,width=15, bd=4,command = ap)
       self.btnAttend.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Below is the code for the attendance page

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
import NEA_SQL_IIII

class Attendance:

   def __init__ (self,root):
       self.root =root
       self.root.title("ODIN Attendance Page")
       self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
       self.root.config(bg="ghost white")
#These are all the entry widgets, where the values will be added
       Absent = BooleanVar()
       AbsenceNote = BooleanVar()
       TotalAbsences = IntVar()
       StudentName = StringVar()
       StudentID = StringVar()
       should_auto = BooleanVar()

       #function
       #This is the section that will give the buttons their functionality
       def Clear():
           self.entStudentID.delete(0,END)
           self.entStudentName.delete(0,END)
           self.chkAbsent.deselect()
           self.chkAbsenceNote.deselect()
           self.entTotalAbsences.delete(0,END)


       def Exit():
           Exit = tk.messagebox.askyesno("ODIN","Do you wish to exit?")
           if Exit > 0:
               root.destroy()
               return

       def searchDatabase():
           attendanceList.delete(0,END)
           for row in NEA_SQL_IIII.searchA(StudentID.get(),StudentName.get()):
               attendanceList.insert(END,row,str(""))


       def viewData():
           attendanceList.delete(0,END)
           for row in NEA_SQL_IIII.displayA():
               attendanceList.insert(END,row,str(""))

       def deleteData():
           if(len(StudentName.get())!=0):
              NEA_SQL_IIII.DeleteDataA(sd[0])
              Clear()
              viewData()

       def AttendRec(event):
           global sd
           searchAttend = attendanceList.curselection()[0]
           sd = attendanceList.get(searchAttend)

           self.entStudentID.delete(0,END)
           self.entStudentID.insert(END,sd[0])
           self.entStudentName.delete(0,END)
           self.entStudentName.insert(END,sd[1])
           self.chkAbsent.deselect()
           self.chkAbsent.select()
           self.chkAbsenceNote.deselect()
           self.chkAbsenceNote.select()
           self.entTotalAbsences.delete(0,END)
           self.entTotalAbsences.insert(END,sd[4])

       def Update():
           if(len(StudentID.get())!=0):
               NEA_SQL_IIII.DeleteDataA(sd[0])
           if(len(StudentID.get())!=0):
               NEA_SQL_IIII.addStudentA(StudentID.get(),StudentName.get(),Absent.get(),AbsenceNote.get(),TotalAbsences.get())
               attendanceList.delete(0,END)
               attendanceList.insert(END,(StudentID.get(),StudentName.get(),Absent.get(),AbsenceNote.get(),TotalAbsences.get()))


       #Frames
       #These will define all the different frames

       MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bg="Ghost White")
       MainFrame.grid()

       TitFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, padx=54, pady=8, bg="Ghost White", relief = RIDGE)
       TitFrame.pack(side=TOP)

       self.lblTit = Label(TitFrame ,font=('ariel', 47,'bold'),text="ODIN Attendance Page",bg="Ghost White")
       self.lblTit.grid()

       ButtonFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, width=1350, height=70, padx=18, pady=10, bg="blue2", relief = RIDGE)
       ButtonFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

       DataFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=1, width=1300, height=400, padx=20, pady=20, bg="ghost white", relief = RIDGE)
       DataFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

       #DataFrameTOP = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=1000, height=300, padx=20, pady=4, relief = RIDGE,  bg="Ghost White", font=('ariel', 20,'bold'), text = "Student Info\n")
       #DataFrameTOP.pack(side=TOP)

       DataFrameLEFT = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=450, height=200, padx=20,pady=3, bg="Ghost White", relief = RIDGE, font=('ariel', 20,'bold'), text = "Student Info\n")
       DataFrameLEFT.pack(side=LEFT)

       DataFrameRIGHT = LabelFrame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=450, height=200, padx=31,pady=3, bg="Ghost White", relief = RIDGE, font=('ariel', 20,'bold'), text = "Student Details\n")
       DataFrameRIGHT.pack(side=RIGHT)

#Label and Entry Widget
#These are the widgets that will allow for labels onto the entry sections


       self.lblStudentID = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Student ID", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
       self.lblStudentID.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
       self.entStudentID = Entry(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=StudentID,  width=39)
       self.entStudentID.grid(row=0, column=1)

       self.lblStudentName = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Student Name", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
       self.lblStudentName.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
       self.entStudentName = Entry(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=StudentName,  width=39)
       self.entStudentName.grid(row=1, column=1)

       self.lblAbsent = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Absent?", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
       self.lblAbsent.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
       self.chkAbsent = Checkbutton(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=Absent, variable = should_auto, onvalue = True, offvalue = False, width=39)
       self.chkAbsent.grid(row=2, column=1)

       self.lblAbsenceNote = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Absence Note?", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
       self.lblAbsenceNote.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
       self.chkAbsenceNote = Checkbutton(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=AbsenceNote,  width=39, onvalue = True, offvalue = False)
       self.chkAbsenceNote.grid(row=3, column=1)

       self.lblTotalAbsences = Label(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),text="Total Absences?", padx=2, pady=2, bg="Ghost White")
       self.lblTotalAbsences.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
       self.entTotalAbsences = Entry(DataFrameLEFT ,font=('ariel', 11,'bold'),textvariable=TotalAbsences,  width=39)
       self.entTotalAbsences.grid(row=4, column=1)



       #scrollbar

       scrollbar = Scrollbar(DataFrameRIGHT)
       scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = 'ns')

       attendanceList = Listbox(DataFrameRIGHT, width=41, height=16, font=('ariel',12,'bold'), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
       attendanceList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',AttendRec)
       attendanceList.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=8)
       scrollbar.config(command = attendanceList.yview)

#button
       #self.btnAddDate = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Add New', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=addData)
       #self.btnAddDate.grid(row=0, column=0)

       self.btnDisplay = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Display', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=viewData)
       self.btnDisplay.grid(row=0, column=0)

       self.btnClear = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Clear', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=Clear)
       self.btnClear.grid(row=0, column=1)

       self.btnDelete = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Delete', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = deleteData)
       self.btnDelete.grid(row=0, column=2)

       self.btnSearch = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Search', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = searchDatabase)
       self.btnSearch.grid(row=0, column=3)

       #self.btnUpdate = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Update', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = updateData)
       #self.btnUpdate.grid(row=0, column=4)

       self.btnUpdate = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Update', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = Update)
       self.btnUpdate.grid(row=0, column=4)

       self.btnQuit = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Quit', font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command=Exit)
       self.btnQuit.grid(row=0, column=5)


if __name__=='__main__':
   root = Tk()
   application = Attendance(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

And below is the SQL code needed (NEA_SQL_IIII)

```
def Attendance():
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST Attendance (Absent BOOLEAN, AbsenceNote BOOLEAN, TotalAbsences INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY StudentName REFERENCES StudentRecord(StudentName),FOREIGN KEY StudentID REFERENCES StudentRecord(StudentID), PRIMARY KEY(StudentID)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def displayA():
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Attendance")
    rows =cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows

def DeleteDataA(StudentID):
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM Attendance WHERE StudentID=?", (StudentID,))
    con.commit()
    return con, cur
    con.close()

def searchA(StudentName="", StudentID=""):
    con=sqlite3.connect("Attendance.db", isolation_level=None)
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE StudentName=? OR StudentID=?", (StudentName,StudentID,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows

def UpdateDataA(StudentID="", StudentName="", Behaviour="", Achievement="", Detention="", ProgressLevel=""):
    con=sqlite3.connect("StudentRecord.db")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE StudentRecord SET StudentName=?, Behaviour=?, Achievement=?, Detention=?, ProgressLevel=? WHERE StudentID=? ", (StudentID,StudentName,Behaviour,Achievement,Detention,ProgressLevel))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run multiple tkinter windows simultaneously from one python process, as tkinter is not thread safe, sometimes it will partially work but unlikely in the way you wish. If you want to run multiple pages I would recommend using a different GUI toolkit or run the tkinter windows from different processess by the use of:

```
import subprocess, sys
subprocess.Popen((sys.executable + '/path/to/file.py').split())
```

If you need to communicate between the processess however it becomes more complicated and I would recommend using `socket` for that.

Comment: Hey, I tried your method and I keep getting the error: "IndexError: string index out of range" Am I missing a line of code

Comment: There shouldn't be any index errors with my answer however, following the code you have above for the applications, the only string that seems to be indexed is the `sd` variable in the second section which is produced from cursor selection, it may be worth inserting a check there to ensure that the strings length is greater than zero, just incase it is that which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With your problem I assume you wish to create lots of Tkinter windows that work together. In which case, I would create multiple .py files and use **a single file where all the windows get their data from**.

I understand that was a bit long-winded, so let me explain...

Firstly, create a central .py file that controls your main window. I would call it something like main.py

Create a new .py file for your new window.

Create a .txt file for all the windows to centrally run off, call it something like data.txt.

Add an import to the other program to begin the data stream between programs and to create the other program window. Then set waiting to True.

Finally, include a While loop for while the seperate window(s) are open and use it to constantly check your data.txt file for any updates. E.g:

```
While waiting == True:
    f = open("data.txt","r")
    recent = f.read() #or do a readline if you want certain data
    if recent == old:
        old = recent
    else:
        old = recent
        #insert what/where you want the data to go after it's updated.
        #you could also add a waiting = False loop if you like, if after the data has been edited you wish the program to stop checking the data.txt file.
        #You can also add code to remotely stop the other window here too if you like.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @FelixLord If you wish for the SQL code to be a separate window (or file or whatever) then I would write it in the data.txt file and use import to control both windows/files. **I am not 100% sure due to context and it's not my code! (please don't take it personally)** but if you wish to do what I outlined in my answer above, then please do.